# How to read input from a file and convert data lines of the file to List[Map[Int,String]] using scala?

Tags: scala, csv, dictionary, reduce, rdd

My Query is, read input from a file and convert data lines of the file to List[Map[Int,String]] using scala. Here I give a dataset as the input. My code is,

```
  def id3(attrs: Attributes,
      examples: List[Example],
      label: Symbol
       ) : Node = {
level = level+1


  // if all the examples have the same label, return a new node with that label

  if(examples.forall( x => x(label) == examples(0)(label))){
  new Leaf(examples(0)(label))
  } else {
  for(a <- attrs.keySet-label){          //except label, take all attrs
    ("Information gain for %s is %f".format(a,
      informationGain(a,attrs,examples,label)))
  }


  // find the best splitting attribute - this is an argmax on a function over the list

  var bestAttr:Symbol = argmax(attrs.keySet-label, (x:Symbol) =>
    informationGain(x,attrs,examples,label))




  // now we produce a new branch, which splits on that node, and recurse down the nodes.

  var branch = new Branch(bestAttr)

  for(v <- attrs(bestAttr)){


    val subset = examples.filter(x=> x(bestAttr)==v)



    if(subset.size == 0){
      // println(levstr+"Tiny subset!")
      // zero subset, we replace with a leaf labelled with the most common label in
      // the examples
      val m = examples.map(_(label))
      val mostCommonLabel = m.toSet.map((x:Symbol) => (x,m.count(_==x))).maxBy(_._2)._1
      branch.add(v,new Leaf(mostCommonLabel))

    }
    else {
      // println(levstr+"Branch on %s=%s!".format(bestAttr,v))

      branch.add(v,id3(attrs,subset,label))
    }
   }
  level = level-1
  branch
  }
  }
  }
object samplet {
def main(args: Array[String]){

var attrs: sample.Attributes = Map()
attrs += ('0 -> Set('abc,'nbv,'zxc))
attrs += ('1 -> Set('def,'ftr,'tyh))
attrs += ('2 -> Set('ghi,'azxc))
attrs += ('3 -> Set('jkl,'fds))
attrs += ('4 -> Set('mno,'nbh))



val examples: List[sample.Example] = List(
  Map(
    '0 -> 'abc,
    '1 -> 'def,
    '2 -> 'ghi,
    '3 'jkl,
    '4 -> 'mno
  ),
  ........................
  )


// obviously we can't use the label as an attribute, that would be silly!
val label = 'play

println(sample.try(attrs,examples,label).getStr(0))

}
}
```

But How I change this code to - accepting input from a **.csv** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read a csv file ,

```
val datalines = Source.fromFile(filepath).getLines()
```

So this **datalines** contains all the lines from the csv file.

Next, convert each line into a **Map[Int,String]**

```
val datamap = datalines.map{ line =>
    line.split(",").zipWithIndex.map{ case (word, idx) => idx -> word}.toMap
    }
```

Here, we split each line with **","**. Then construct a map with **key** as *column* number and **value** as each *word* after the split.

Next, If we want **List[Map[Int,String]]**,

```
val datamap = datalines.map{ line =>
    line.split(",").zipWithIndex.map{ case (word, idx) => idx -> word}.toMap
    }.toList
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use Java's io / nio standard library to read your CSV file. I think there is no relevant drawback in doing so.

But the first question we need to answer is **where to read the file in the code?** The parsed input seems to replace the value of `examples`. This fact also hints us what **type** the parsed CSV input must have, namely `List[Map[Symbol, Symbol]]`. So let us declare a new class

```
class InputFromCsvLoader(charset: Charset = Charset.defaultCharset()) {
  def getInput(file: Path): List[Map[Symbol, Symbol]] = ???
}
```

Note that the `Charset` is only needed if we must distinguish between differently encoded CSV-files.

Okay, so how do we implement the method? It should do the following:

1. Create an appropriate input reader
2. Read all lines
3. Split each line at the comma-separator
4. Transform each substring into the symbol it represents
5. Build a map from from the list of symbols, using the `attributes` as key
6. Create and return the list of maps

Or expressed in code:

```
class InputFromCsvLoader(charset: Charset = Charset.defaultCharset()) {
  val Attributes = List('outlook, 'temperature, 'humidity, 'wind, 'play)
  val Separator = ","

  /** Get the desired input from the CSV file. Does not perform any checks, i.e., there are no guarantees on what happens if the input is malformed. */
  def getInput(file: Path): List[Map[Symbol, Symbol]] = {
    val reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)
    /* Read the whole file and discard the first line */
    inputWithHeader(reader).tail
  }

  /** Reads all lines in the CSV file using [[java.io.BufferedReader]] There are many ways to do this and this is probably not the prettiest. */
  private def inputWithHeader(reader: BufferedReader): List[Map[Symbol, Symbol]] = {
    (JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(reader.lines().iterator()) foldLeft Nil.asInstanceOf[List[Map[Symbol, Symbol]]]){
      (accumulator, nextLine) =>
        parseLine(nextLine) :: accumulator
    }.reverse
  }

  /** Parse an entry. Does not verify the input: If there are less attributes than columns or vice versa, zip creates a list of the size of the shorter list */
  private def parseLine(line: String): Map[Symbol, Symbol] = (Attributes zip (line split Separator map parseSymbol)).toMap

  /** Create a symbol from a String... we could also check whether the string represents a valid symbol */
  private def parseSymbol(symbolAsString: String): Symbol = Symbol(symbolAsString)
}
```

**Caveat:** Expecting only valid input, we are certain that the individual symbol representations do not contain the comma-separation character. If this cannot be assumed, then the code as is would fail to split certain valid input strings.

To use this new code, we could change the `main`-method as follows:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
  val csvInputFile: Option[Path] = args.headOption map (p => Paths get p)
  val examples = (csvInputFile map new InputFromCsvLoader().getInput).getOrElse(exampleInput)
  // ... your code
```

Here, `examples` uses the value `exampleInput`, which is the current, hardcoded value of `examples` if no input argument is specified.

**Important:** In the code, all error handling has been omitted for convenience. In most cases, errors can occur when reading from files and user input must be considered invalid, so sadly, error handling at the boundaries of your program is usally not optional.

**Side-notes:**

- Try not to use `null` in your code. Returning `Option[T]` is a better option than returning `null`, because it makes "nullness" explicit and provides static safety thanks to the type-system.
- The `return`-keyword is not required in Scala, as the last value of a method is always returned. You can still use the keyword if you find the code more readable or if you want to break in the middle of your method (which is usually a bad idea).
- Prefer `val` over `var`, because immutable values are much easier to understand than mutable values.
- The code will fail with the provided CSV string, because it contains the symbols `TRUE` and `FALSE` which are not legal according to your programs logic (they should be `true` and `false` instead).
- Add all information to your error-messages. Your error message only tells me what that a value for  the attribute `'wind` is bad, but it does not tell me what the actual value is.

Comment: I gt error in val reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset) => cannot resolve symbol newBufferedReader,  val csvInputFile: Option[Path] = args.headOption map (p => Paths get p) => cannot resolve symbol paths, (JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(reader.lines().iterator()) => cannot resolve symbol lines().

Comment: @rosy I am so sorry: I didn't see a notification of your comments. The Java code I wrote requires Java 8 (`reader.lines()`) and Java 7 (`Files.newBufferedReader()` and `Paths.get()`, aswell as the type `Path`); the error is most likely related to you using an older version of Java. However, you can create a `BufferedReader` from a `java.io.File` to read the file. There are a lot of ways to read a file and the most common of them are surely found here on StackOverflow. My point here was simply that there's no drawback in using I/O functionality provided by the Java standard library.